# How to count data with specific values and for specific user/person (in row)?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, count

I have one problem, which I can't handle...

My PostgreSQL table looks like that:

```
id student grade class gradeDate
1     1      5     1       2017-03-03
2     1      5     1       2017-03-04
3     1      1     1       2017-03-05
4     1      5     1       2017-03-06
5     1      5     1       2017-03-07
6     1      5     1       2017-03-08
7     1      1     1       2017-03-09
8     2      5     2       2017-03-03
9     3      5     3       2017-03-03
```

So I have different students (1,2,3...) in different classes (1,2,3,4...), who gets grade EVERY DAY (gradeDate)
 - it can be only 5 or 1 - and now I want to select from this database the biggest count of grade 5 in row for each student (by in row I mean grade 5 every day without break)
So in the table above the biggest count for user 1 will be 3 (row 4,5,6), for user 2 will be 1 and for user 3 will be one.
If I change grade in row 3 for 5, the biggest count will be 6 for student 1 
Do you get the idea?

At first I wanted to use somehow SELECT query, but firstly - I don't know how to make this query and secondly - when there will be thousands or millions of rows in this
table, the efficiency of that query will be very, very low.
I can normally get every rows for student 1 and manipulate it in Java.
So I ask - how can I solve this problem?
Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: What if a student is in multiple classes?

Comment: It is impossible. Every student has only one class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify adjacent groups.  One simple method is the difference of row numbers.  To really understand it, you'll need to run the subquery and stare at the results.  You should "see" how the difference defines the groups.

```
select student, class, grade, count(*), min(gradeDate), max(gradeDate)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by student, class, grade order by gradeDate) as seqnum_scg,
             row_number() over (partition by student, class order by gradeDate) as seqnum_sc
      from t
     ) t
group by student, class, grade, (seqnum_sc - seqnum_scg);
```

To get the maximum, you can then use `distinct on`.  I'll use a subquery for that:

```
select distinct on (student, class) scg.*
from (select student, class, grade, count(*) as cnt,
             min(gradeDate), max(gradeDate), min_gradeDate, max_gradeDate
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by student, class, grade order by gradeDate) as seqnum_scg,
                   row_number() over (partition by student, class order by gradeDate) as seqnum_sc
            from t
           ) t
      where grade = 5
      group by student, class, grade, (seqnum_sc - seqnum_scg)
     ) scg
order by student, class, cnt desc;
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, but what about "efficiency" of that solution if the table will have thousands/millions of rows? What I mean is - I need to have the maximum immediately - user can't wait for example 3/5 seconds for query to return good value. Will it still work well in that case?

Comment: @Pirki . . . This is going to be the most efficient way to get the results that you want.

Comment: I don't think so... The problem is that I have to fire this query every time user clicks one thing on website, so in my opinion I'll have to wait for the result and if 1000-10000 users click it in one moment, DB will be too charged. Anybody have another idea?

Comment: @Pirki . . . Whether or not it meets your performance needs is rather unrelated to whether or not it is the best approach.  You may not be able to do what you want with the data structure at hand.