# How to rewrite query which gives amount of specific value in row to avoid some values and count further with others?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, distinct

I have a query which gives me amount of grade 5 for every student in row (if student don't have any other grade on the way):

```
select distinct on (student, class) scg.*
from (select student, class, grade, count(*) as cnt,
         min(gradeDate), max(gradeDate), min_gradeDate, max_gradeDate
  from (select t.*,
               row_number() over (partition by student, class, grade order by gradeDate) as seqnum_scg,
               row_number() over (partition by student, class order by gradeDate) as seqnum_sc
        from t
       ) t
  where grade = 5
  group by student, class, grade, (seqnum_sc - seqnum_scg)
 ) scg
order by student, class, cnt desc;
```

The original problem is explained here:
[How to count data with specific values and for specific user/person (in row)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46245647/how-to-count-data-with-specific-values-and-for-specific-user-person-in-row)

But now I want to extend this query with one more feature. This counter gives me max value unless some student have grade 4/3/2/1, but now I want it to:

- stop counting if student has 4 or 3 grade and start over (with previous max) when student get another 5
  What I mean:

Actual query: 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2 --> gives me max = 3

New query: 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2 --> gives me max = 5, because 4 and 3 stop counter and start it when user gets another 5

- stop counting if student gets grade 2 or 1 (and give me max value before getting 2/1 grade) So the same thing which query does now for every grade except 5, but I want it only for 2 and lower (that I can specify in query).

Can someone help me rewrite the second query given by @Gordon Linoff to work like that and tell me what changed?

Edit: examples as requested:

```
id student grade class gradeDate
1     1      5     1       2017-03-03
2     1      5     1       2017-03-04
3     1      1     1       2017-03-05
4     1      5     1       2017-03-06
5     1      5     1       2017-03-07
6     1      5     1       2017-03-08
7     1      1     1       2017-03-09
8     2      5     2       2017-03-03
9     3      5     3       2017-03-03
10    4      5     4       2017-03-03
11    4      5     4       2017-03-04
12    4      4     4       2017-03-05
13    4      3     4       2017-03-06    
14    4      5     4       2017-03-07
15    4      5     4       2017-03-08
16    5      5     5       2017-03-01
17    5      5     5       2017-03-03
18    5      5     5       2017-03-04
19    5      5     5       2017-03-05
20    5      5     5       2017-03-06
21    5      2     5       2017-03-07
22    5      5     5       2017-03-08
23    5      5     5       2017-03-09
```

Student one : max = 3

Student two : max = 1

Student three : max = 1

Student four : max = 4 (grade 4 and 3 stop counter, but don't reset it)

Student five : max = 5 (because grade 2 reset counter, lack of grade on date 
2017-03-02 is not a problem for counter)

Comment: The best you can do here is to post some sample data and your expected result.

Comment: I gave examples. Student 4 and 5 situations show what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

One of the methods can be using 2 subqueries and one analytic function

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/74b71/10

```
SELECT student, max( xxx )
FROM (
   SELECT student, grp_nbr, count(CASE WHEN grade = 5 THEN 1 END) As xxx
   FROM (
      SELECT *,
             SUM (  CASE WHEN grade in (1,2)
                         THEN 1 ELSE 0
                    END 
             ) OVER (Partition by student Order By gradeDate ) As grp_nbr
      FROM table1
   ) x
   GROUP BY student, grp_nbr
) y
GROUP BY student
ORDER BY student
```

---

```
| student | max |
|---------|-----|
|       1 |   3 |
|       2 |   1 |
|       3 |   1 |
|       4 |   4 |
|       5 |   5 |
```

Comment: It works! But one more thing - where to write "WHERE" clause? I want it to SELECT WHERE student = 1 for example. (I'm not really SQL Master :P)

Comment: Put it in the innermost subquery, just behind `FROM table1` ==> `..... FROM Table1 WHERE student = 1`